# react-leaflet, how I can search exact marker by marker id in react-leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, openstreetmap, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3, react-leaflet-search

I want to search exact marker using marker key or id in react-leaflet? is it posible? can someone help me. i am new for react-leaflet

I added some markers on my map. now i want to add search bar and i need to find exact marker using marker key,name,id or anything.

```
const renderPlants = (plants) => {
    let plant = plants.filter(v => v?.longitude !== null);
      return plant?.map((item) => {
        var today = new Date();
        var dateofPlanting = new Date(item?.dateofPlanting);
        const diffTime = Math.abs(today - dateofPlanting);
        const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        const isExpired = (diffDays > 1460) ? (true) : (false);
        const invested = (item?.investment===1) ? (true) : (false);
          return (
            
            <Marker
            key={item.treeID}
              eventHandlers={{
                mouseover: (event) => event.target.openPopup(),
                click: (e) => {
                  showModal(item, invested, isExpired );
                },
              }}
              position={[item?.latitude, item?.longitude]} 
              icon={(isExpired) ? (markerIconGold) :  (item?.investment) ? (markerIconSilver) : (markerIconGreen)}>
              <Popup>{item.treeID}</Popup>
      </Marker>
          )
      })
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

With react-leaflet I like to just see the leaflet part as a canvas. You control the state from the outside. You will do the search on the state in your case `plants`  and then you will just filter out the markers matching the search condition in your render function:

```
const renderPlants = (plants, searchCondition) => {
    let plant = plants.filter(v => v?.longitude !== null).filter(p=> searchCondition(p));
```